# Phusion Passenger ngnix.conf location

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I have a Rails 3 application that uses Phusion Passenger. I install the standalone version of Passenger using the command "gem install passenger" on my Macintosh MacBook Pro. The application works fine. Now, I want to change some configurations for the ngnix server but I can not find the location of the ngnix.conf file. I have looked in /usr/local and /opt/ and /etc/.  Can someone assist me in either finding or creating the ngnix.conf?

Thanks

Comment: If you're using the default ruby, try looking somewhere in `/Library/Ruby/Gems`, which is where the default OSX ruby keeps it's rubygems. If you're using RVM, you'll probably find something in ~/.rvm/

Answer (score 1):

Look for the nginx.conf file in /opt/nginx/conf

You must have su privileges to edit this file.

Remember to stop and start nginx after making your changes